# Self-made image carousel not looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a weird bug with my self-made jQuery image carousel. I also have already checked the suggested similar topics and they didn't help. So it's a simple six images with a next arrow and prev arrow. If you get to the end using the prev arrow then it loops to the last image successfully, but if you try to go back to the first image from the last using the next arrow it takes two extra clicks and after the first click it screws up the page and makes everything out of order. Any suggestions?

**JavaScript**

```
$('.arrow-prev').click(function() {
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

    if(prevSlide.length === 0) {
        prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
    }

    currentSlide.removeClass('active-slide');
    prevSlide.addClass('active-slide');
});

$('.arrow-next').click(function() {
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

    if(nextSlide.length === 0) {
        nextSlide = $('.active-slide');
    }

    currentSlide.removeClass('active-slide');
    nextSlide.addClass('active-slide');
});
```

(Relevant) **HTML**

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide active-slide">
        <img src="img/image-2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="img/image-3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="img/image-4.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="img/image-5.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="img/image-1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="img/image-6.jpg">
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="arrow-prev"><img src="img/Arrow-Prev.png" width="75px" height="75px"></a>
    <a href="#" class="arrow-next"><img src="img/Arrow-Next.png" width="75px" height="75px"></a>
</div>
```

(Relevant) **CSS**

```
.slider {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 9%;
}

.slide {
    display: none;
}

.active-slide {
    display: block;
}

.slider img {
    max-width: 90%;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.slider .arrow-prev {
    margin-left: 13%;
}

.slider .arrow-next {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 25%;
}
```

Comment: A live example reproducing the problem would be nice

Comment: @AndrewL. [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/btyxcu7s/) with some stock photos of nature :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues with your code for the next function.

1. The `next()` element of the last slide will be the `a` tag therefore the length is always `> 0`. You can evaluate if the next is an "slide" element:

   ```
   var nextSlide = currentSlide.next('.slide');
   ```
2. If nextslide doesn't exist you need to go to the `first()` element:

   ```
   nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
   ```

---

[**Updated Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/btyxcu7s/2/)

<sub>Thanks to @Jonathan Lam for the demo</sub>

Comment: You just beat me to finding this out as I was fiddling around with it; and you're very welcome for the demo :)

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me and you gave such a quick response. :)

Comment: glad to help U @JacobRodgers

Answer (score 2):

```
nextslide=$(".activeslide")
```

in your if statement will not work because the activeslide is your current slide. The script will do nothing
What about

```
nextslide=$(".slide").first()
```

?